# Atribuir retorno Tuple em duas variáveis

Tags: c#, tupla

Tem um método que retorna uma tupla com duas `strings`.

O retorno eu quero gravar em duas variáveis diferentes, só que estou tendo que chamar o método duas vezes para pegar um item de cada vez.

```
string retorno1 = SearchTerra(artista, musica).item1;

string retorno2 = SearchTerra(artista, musica).item2;
```

Teria como fazer isso chamando 1 vez só?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem.

É só criar uma tupla pra receber o retorno

```
(string retorno1, string retorno2) = SearchTerra(artista, musica);
```

Ou então

```
var tupla = SearchTerra(artista, musica);

// Acessando
tupla.item1;
tupla.item2;
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/R7w1ay)

Answer (score 2):

Tem.

```
var tupla = SearchTerra(artista, musica);
string retorno1 = tupla.item1;
string retorn2 = tupla.item2;
```